# Class not found in directory

Tags: php, namespaces

I've got some classes organized in namespaces, like this:

**src/bases/BaseObject.php**

```
<?php
namespace API\bases;

use \API\system\Database as Database;

class BaseObject {
    protected $db = null;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = Database::instance();
    }

}
```

**src/objects/User.php**

```
<?php
namespace API\objects;

class User extends \API\bases\BaseObject {

}
```

**src/autoload.php**

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(
    function($class) {
        $path_parts = explode("\\", $class);

        if ($path_parts[0] == 'API') {
            array_shift($path_parts);
        }
        require(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path_parts) . ".php");
    }
);
```

I've already implemented other classes, but in this case, when I instanciate a User object, it returns this fatal:

```
Fatal error: Class 'API\bases\BaseObject' not found in /realpath/to/api/src/objects/User.php on line 4
```

`User.php:4` is the `class User extends \API\bases\BaseObject {` line. To me, it doesn't make sense, since I've used it in another class inheritance as well, the same way. Do you see anything I skipped?

**Edit:** Worth noting that I manually required the class, and it told `could not redeclare class`, so it seems to be found anyway.

Comment: You have to include your User.php in autoload.php file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The autoload.php requires the file automatically. No need to do so. Without extending the other object it was working well

Comment: 1. `use` always starts from the root, so it doesn't need a leading `\\``. 2. It's usually good practice to 'use' ALL used classes in a file, so you don't make things like `extends \API\bases\BaseObject` 3. No need to use `as` if the class base name is the same: "Database". -- Sorry, couldn't help myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, because I have rewritten three times the class, but it looks like there was a space giving issues in the BaseObject class. I removed the space between `BaseObject` and the open curly brace, and it worked.

Comment: It truly was. My bets are there was an invisible symbol giving issues after a nasty copy paste

Comment: Ah yes, zero width characters. The bane of our existence. Word-style: backspace, enter, backspace, backspace, backspace, re-type a character, enter, enter, backspace. Until you find the magic combo =)